# How to access python code imported as a module

Tags: python, pandas, module

I have a py script which, should be used to perform different operations on a excel file.
This script imports other py scripts as modules.
Unfortunately, I don't have an executable version of this script to be able to use it as a desktop app and I don't have access to those scripts imported as modules.

It may seem a weird question but is there a way to access the code of a python script imported as a module within another python if I don't have access to it?

For example the script I'm having is named my_script.py

```
#imports
  import pandas as pd
  import json
  import io

#importing python script as module
  import script1 --the script for which I don't have the code(without this script I can't use my_script.py)
```

So I am trying to see if there is a way to access the code from script1 so I can save it on the same folder with my_script.py

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: " is there a way to access the code of a python script imported as a module within another python if I don't have access to it?" This sounds like a contradiction... "how can I access X if I don't have access to X?" Well, you *can't*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have updated the question. I know that sounds a bit SF but how can python work with imported scripts as modules in executable versions, somehow it reads them, right? Why can't that be accomplished within a py code?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "I don't have access to this script". What  do you mean? Can you `import script1`? Because *then you have access to it*. If you can't, then I really don't know what you mean.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, I can't use my_script.py because contains an imported script as module(script1) and I don't have that script.

Comment: So then we are right back to that... if you *don't have access to it*, then *you don't have access to it*. If I write `import foo` in a python script... and there is no `foo` that I can import... *what do you expect to be able to do with that?*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well, I know that makes sense, thx for the confirmation

Comment: Did you just find a random script with no information on how it is supposed to be installed? So there are just random imports in it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, I used this script in the past but I lost the imported script. I have all the code for the initial script(my_script.py), less for the one imported and without it, I can't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense in the sense that you clearly have to have read permissions to the file you want to read, if you want to read the file. So, no if you don't have permission to read a file then you can't access it and read it. If however, importing the file works for you (since you can read it), then you should be able to access the source code.

In general, the standard library `inspect` is used to deal with things like this:

```
import re
import inspect
source_python_code = inspect.getsource(re.findall)
print(source_python_code)
```

Keep in mind that this will only work so far. You can't inspect already compiled code for example (python isn't going to magically reverse engineer the compiled code for you on the fly). There are other things too, like decorators that can cause the line numbers to be inaccurate and produce the wrong code, etc.

If instead you wanted the actual compiled python bytes that are in memory for the functions you are using, then that is already accessible with the `__code__` method. For example,

```
print(re.findall.__code__.co_code)
```

Comment: AFAIKT doesn't have anything to do with read permissions. The OP literally no longer has access to some other `.py` file they used to have. Basically, they are asking for a logical contradiction.

Comment: Well if the OP imports from file.py and file.py imports from script.py, then presumably script.py is accessible by file.py and is readable by the user. Otherwise file.py would have failed to import. In any case, I suppose we both agree by the confusion.

Comment: Read through the comments, the OP *cannot use either* for precisely that reason: "No, I used this script in the past but I lost the imported script. I have all the code for the initial script(my_script.py), less for the one imported and without it, I can't use it anymore"

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, if you can import it, you definitely have access to the script. But if you really want to do it this way:

```
import inspect
import script1
    
print(inspect.getsource(script1))
```

Just to show you what the others mean. Try doing this:

```
print(script1.__file__)
```

This will give you the path from where you're importing the module. You should be able to open that file and look at the source code.

Comment: *the OP cannot import it*.